# Roll 2 dice, what's the probability that at least one will come up 6?

Tags: probability

Let $P(E)$ be the probability that at least one roll out of the two will come up as 6. I thought of doing $P(E)=1-P(E^{c})$, which is basically $1-P($neither of the 2 rolls are 6$)$. So $P(E)=1-(\frac{5}{6})(\frac{5}{6})=\frac{11}{36}$, correct?

Comment: Excellent! In questions with 'at least' or 'at most' in it, always investigate the complement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your answer is indeed correct.

Comment: I added an answer so that this question will not remain unanswered.